# AWS Elastic Beanstalk - Opening IIS Page

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I hosted my web-app in AWS Elastic Beanstalk.

Howover when I use the URL of the my application, is opening the IIS page and not openning my application.

How to do for open my application? Can be open the login page. (login/login)

Comment: What solution stack did you use? did you ssh into the instance and verified that your code is running?

Comment: I use Visual Studio 2015. .Net 4.5.2. It is this error in my deploy (only in AWS) "Deployment Failed: Unexpected Exception". But I don't know how to see more details

Comment: You can RDP into the instance and see whether you can find more detailed something in CFN/logs. Or you can pull your logs from the AWS console. I assume that you are using the VS plugin for AWS? If yes, deploying a standard web app (that works locally) is normally a very straightforward process, just working through the wizard the first time and creating the application and its environment.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this problem recently. My application was running fine as a Single Instance, but when I changed to a Load Balanced/Auto Scaling environment the application just got stuck in the IIS Welcome Page for hours.

So I created a new, fresh application environment, but this time unchecking the *Single instance environment* checkbox in the *Publish to AWS* wizard, to start with a Load Balanced environment from the get-go. The application started working again.